# handling of checkboxes in an openWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I would like to display an infoWindow when I right click a marker.
The infoWindow must display 4 checkboxes according to values.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"rightclick", function()
    { 
        html = "<table><tr><td>";
        if (value1==...) 
        {
            html = html + "<input type='checkbox' id='option1' checked>value1<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            html = html + "<input type='checkbox' id='option1'>value1<br>";    
        }
        if (value2==...) 
        {
            html = html + "<input type='checkbox' id='option2'checked>value2<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            html = html + "<input type='checkbox' id='option2' >value2<br>"; 
        }
        if (value3==...) 
        {
            html = html + "<input type='checkbox' id='option3' checked>value3<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            html = html + "<input type='checkbox' id='option3' >value3<br>";   
        }
        if (value4==...) 
        {
            html = html + "<input type='checkbox' id='option4' checked>value4<br>"; 
        }
        else
        {
            html = html + "<input type='checkbox' id='option4' >value4<br>"; 
        }
        html = html + "</td></tr></table>";
        marker.setContent(html)
        infoWindow.open(map,marker);    
    });
```

1) Do you see a better implementation with jquery because this code is not elegant ?
2) If I click the checkbox #N, how to modify the value of the corresponding valueN ?

Comment: dafuq why not `+=` and why not SWITCH!!!?

Comment: How can you use switch if you're testing different variables?

Comment: ok for switch and += and what about jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this

```
var 
 values = [],
 html = '';

for(i=1;i<n;i++) {
 html += '<input type="checkbox" id="option"'+i+'" '+(values[i] == 'something' ? 'checked' : '')+'> value '+i+'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: this is for the javascript part of the question. how can I know that a checkbox was set/unset by using jquery ?